# Mulesoft - How to find Http error payload in exception object?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

How to find Http error payload in exception object ?

System 1 -> Call's Mule server . Mule server -> Docusign / some one else.

Docusign / some one returns 400 error with json payload (includes errorCode etc)

I need to return the exact details back to System 1.

how will i do this?

1) I did try to add all codes in success codes 200..599, then even error is having 200 ok . This will cause more problem, because I have to add lot of choice routing as some flows are having more data conversion.

2) Ideal soln -> Raise exception as usual. This has to be caught in choice exception. Now I have to send the same status_code and the json response back to the caller.

Issue -? how can i find the payload returned by HTTP in exception object. Where is stored in exception object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample- one way of handling this kind of scenario , use `validation Component` to throw exception and capture in your mainflow either by exceptionHandling or by APIKIT ExceptionHandling

```
 <flow name="routeexceptionFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/in" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="200..599"/>
    </http:request>
    <validation:is-false config-ref="Validation_Configuration" message="#[payload]" exceptionClass="nz.co.exception.BadRequestException" expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] ==400]" doc:name="Validate Bad Request"/>
    <validation:is-false config-ref="Validation_Configuration" message="#[payload]" expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] !=200]" doc:name="Capture all other Exceptions"/>
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causeMatches('nz.co.exception.BadRequestException')]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="#[exception.message]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <logger message="****log all other exception****" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Add this class in your java folder

```
  package nz.co.exception;

   public class BadRequestException extends Exception {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 8546839078847602529L;

    public BadRequestException() {
    super();
    }

    public BadRequestException(String message) {
    super(message);
    }

   public BadRequestException(Throwable t) {
    super(t);
   }

  public BadRequestException(String message, Throwable t) {
    super(message, t);
  }
}
```

In your project if you are using APIKIT Router , then instead of using exceptionHandling as above, add directly `nz.co.exception.BadRequestException` in 400 ReturnCode apikitExceptionHandling.

Comment: I did use a similar stuff as the soln . Thanks for that